# How to customize statusbar in eclipse?

Tags: eclipse, rcp, status, e4

The plugin I made provides a tree viewer, and I want to display the number of items selected in the tree viewer in the status bar like eclipse's progressView.

How should I configure it?

Comment: Is this really an e4 RCP (using an Application.e4xmi and not using any org.eclipse.ui plug-ins)? Or is it a plug-in for the standard Eclipse RCP? The answer is very different depending on the type of RCP

Comment: @greg-449  yes... e4 RCP..

Comment: A plain e4 RCP has no status bar, it is up to you to code the whole thing. Possibly in a `TrimBar` at the bottom of the main window.